# How to switch between subviews in a single view in an Ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework

Within an `ion-view`, I would like the ability to switch between three regions or subviews, with only one view visible at a time. Could sort of view it as "tabs" within the view.

```
  ... content above ...
+-----------------------+
| Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3 |
+-----------------------+
|                       |
|     tab 1 content     |
+-----------------------+
  ... content below ...
```

Is it possible to use `ion-tabs` to do this (or some other mechanism), or would this require a custom directive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can.

You have to use the **Tabs** [directive](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#tabs).

You can place a `<ion-tabs>` inside your `<ion-view>`.
Now you can add `<ion-tab>` to declare the content of each tab.

```
<ion-view view-title="home">

    <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only tabs-striped tabs-top">

        <ion-tab title="Tab1" icon-on="ion-ios-home" icon-off="ion-ios-home-outline">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-1">
              <ion-content padding="true" has-header="true">
                  <h1>HOME</h1>
              </ion-content>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Tab2" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-2">
              <ion-content padding="true" has-header="true">
                  <h1>SETTINGS</h1>
              </ion-content>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Tab3" icon-on="ion-ios-information" icon-off="ion-ios-information-outline">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-3">
              <ion-content padding="true" has-header="true">
                  <h1>INFO</h1>
              </ion-content>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>

</ion-view>
```

If you want to see how it works you can check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cuFY80WIV2XDHpZDn2u4?p=preview).

You can read this [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#striped-style-tabs) to find out how to apply different styles.

Comment: This is good. Thank you. Made a pass using a similar setup, but didn't get the results I was after. This looks good.